# PyCharm multiple file watchers output

Tags: python, pycharm, static-analysis

I have added multiple PyCharm file watchers for my Python project to run several linting tools (flake8, black, isort, etc.). Some of them provide useful output, when there are formatting and style issues. This output gets written to console, but it seems like the output of the last tool in the pipeline overwrites the output of the previous tools.

I would like to know, if someone managed to work around this or if this is known problem (being tracked upstream).

[image: screenshot of the configuration of the "black" file watcher (the others just have the same settings, but invoke a different tool)]

Comment: Yikes, this problem is still pending from 6 years ago. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14387

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Surprisingly, I just updated to 2021.1 and can confirm now it is fixed!

Comment: Eventually one has to increase the visibility of bugs on StackO in order to get them fixed :D

Comment: Maybe this particular thing is fixed (preventing a different filewatcher replacing tht output), but the output from filewatchers still replace any "regular" output from a script you've run, making the feature useless.